# Where does HttpRuntime.Cache store data?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I was thinking about implementing some caching in my ASP.NET web application to improve performance.  I read about HttpRuntime.Cache and it seems like that is what it was made for.  The only issue is that I want to potentially cache a lot of data (mainly SQL query results).  So, **I wanted to know where HttpRuntime.Cache stores data...is it in memory or on the HD somewhere?**

If it stores in memory, then I am potentially overloading the server's resources, so I would need an alternative cache store.  I was thinking MongoDB might be a good option, unless anyone else has a better suggestion...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored in memory according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx)

> An application can often increase performance by storing data in
>   memory

Which could possibly be stored on the hard drive depending on the utilization of the Page file. Be especially careful to not create references to objects you don't want to store.